# Wireless can connect to network but I can't ping any address or browse the web

Tags: debian, wifi

**Edit: I have two copies of this card and when I try to make it work on an other computer with Debian 8 (freshly installed), I have exactly the same problem.**

I'm trying to install a wireless network card (Asus PCE-N15) on an Gigabyte motherboard, my wire connection is working correctly, but with the wireless, I can connect to my Internet box but I have no Internet connection.

I run on Debian 8 Jessie and I have the package network-manager installed.

Firstly, the card has two LEDs but this is the orange one and not the green one which is lit. Nothing can be done physically on the wireless card (there is no button).

The card is detected as it is shown by the following command:

```
lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Here is the result of ifconfig:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99  
      inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:21:31:56  
      inet addr:192.168.0.110  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe21:3156/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16042 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9325 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:22390273 (21.3 MiB)  TX bytes:865780 (845.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:37350 (36.4 KiB)  TX bytes:37350 (36.4 KiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:dd:a9:2e:1d:74  
      inet addr:192.168.0.112  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::16dd:a9ff:fe2e:1d74/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:18113 (17.6 KiB)  TX bytes:20839 (20.3 KiB)
```

Is it a problem that the wireless is on wlan1 instead of wlan0?

Here is the file `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan1
```

As shown bellow, I think that the gateway is correctly configured, isn't it?

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan1  proto static  metric 1024 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.23
```

If I try to ping any address on my subnet I receive this:

```
From 192.168.0.17 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

If I try to ping an address outside of my subnet it seems to take an infinite time without any response.

I have now no idea of what to do in order to make it work...

Comment: You probably need to set the routes so that they all point via `wlan1` rather than `eth0`. If you aren't actually wired-connected, the `eth0` routes will create confusion. (If you are wired-connected, you probably want to yank the wire in order to test wireless, at least.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made all my tests with the wire unplugged. Can you please explain me how to set the routes?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the older `route` command, not the newer `ip route`. Using that, you would `route del` every route that refers to eth0, then `route add` (at least) one route for 192.168.0.0/24 through wlan1 and a default route using 192.168.0.1 as a gateway. See the man page for specific syntax.

Comment: I edited my post to show the new routes printed by the ip route show comand. Does it seem better to you now? It still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Temporarily disable your firewall (with `sudo iptables -F`) and try to ping your default gateway (`192.168.0.1`).

Comment: I still have the same result (nothing happens)

Comment: Can you ping your local?

Comment: Yes I can ping my local

Comment: Did you assign that address and set up that route statically, or did you receive them with DHCP? What does `ping 192.168.0.1` say? Has another machine (or the same machine running a different OS) worked on that wifi network?

Comment: I did not assign anything so I think that I receive them with DHCP. ping 192.168.0.1 gives no response. and yes there is an other machine working on this network.

Answer (score 1):

The line `auto wlan1` only brings the interface up but doesn't configure it. That is why it's there but doesn't transmit. You should also configure it using, say `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` (on the next line). `iface` says it's an interface configuration stanza; `wlan1` is the name; `inet` says it concerns TCP/IP traffic and `dhcp` says how it is to be configured. Than `service networking restart` to bring it up and configure it. See http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/interfaces/.

Comment: I added this line to my /etc/network/interfaces file but without success, it still can connect to my modem but it still take an infinite time to access a web page...

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try and edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and just change the name of the port to `wlan0`, if you think it's a problem.

Suspicious you don't have a `wlan0`?  It must think something is there, maybe that's the problem. I've always referred to these as firmware, since they are at such a low level, hierarchically speaking.  It might be simpler to do it this way, as I do on my Debian box.  I change it in interfaces...

Comment: I don't think that it is a problem, I was solely asking to be sure it is not. Anyway I didn't manage to change it from wlan1 to wlan0...

Answer (score 0):

You have two interfaces (`wlan1` and another) that are both with an address on `192.168.0.*/24`.

You have `wlan1` defined as `192.168.0.16` but when you tried to `ping` you received a message from your other local interface `192.168.0.17` saying it had no route to the subnet; this is probably because it's disconnected.

Take a look at the output of `netstat -i` and for each of the listed interfaces check the IP addresses with `ip route show`. You can even do this with a little one-liner:

```
for intf in $(netstat -i | awk '$NF!~/L/ && $NF~/RU/{print $1}'); do echo "$intf -" $(ip addr show "$intf" | awk '$1=="inet"{print $2}' | xargs); done
```

---

If you're curious here's an expanded version of the same code that is probably a little easier to read:

```
# Get the list of interfaces (netstat -i) that are Running and Up but not Loopback
intfs=$(netstat -i | awk '$NF !~ /L/ && $NF ~ /RU/ {print $1}')
echo "Interfaces: $intfs"

# Iterate across the list
for intf in $intfs
do
    # Get the IPv4 addresses associated with this interface (ip addr show wlan1)
    addrs=$(ip addr show "$intf" | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}' | xargs)
    echo "Interface $intf has address ${addrs:-<none>}" 
done
```

Comment: Here is the result of the one-liner command: `eth0 - 192.168.0.110/24
wlan1 - 192.168.0.112/24` when the Ethernet cable is plugged otherwise it is

`eth0 -
wlan1 - 192.168.0.112/24`

Comment: Thus, I have indeed two addresses with an address on 192.168.0.*/24 but can you please explain me what can I do in order to avoid this?

Comment: @user3683807 wired ethernet takes precedence over wireless. If you're not using your ethernet connection you need to disconnect it or tell Network Manager not to assign it an address. With DHCP this should be happening automatically. Maybe you have an entry for `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` that's overriding NM?

Comment: I make all my test with the wire unplugged. That's possible, I edited my post to show what is in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: @user3683807 try `ifconfig eth0 inet 0.0.0.0 down`. A little over the top but quite effective. I don't see why NM isn't doing this for you when you disconnect the cable, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work better...

Comment: @user3683807 if you repeat the little one-liner, do you see that `eth0` is now either omitted or with `<none>` interfaces?

Comment: It is still the same result: eth0 -
wlan1 - 192.168.0.120/24 (eth0 is with <none> interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed in my network, but the problem was in router security settings.

Maybe the issue is in the security settings from the router, according to this link: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1533/

In the router page, I discovered that the MAC address from my laptop was in a "Blocked DoS Host List", then I cleaned this list. Additionally, I increased the threshold values to 500.

Answer (score -1):

First ping localhost it mast answer, the ping the gateway probably 192.168.0.1 if it doesn`t answer then you have a problem with the driver try /etc/init.d/networking restart. If nothing works change the driver. Look for it at the makers web.

Comment: I can ping localhost but not the gateway (it doesn't answer). /etc/init.d/networking restart doesn't change anything. Are you sure that it can come from the driver knowing the card is recognized?